# django cms permissions per language

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

It is very easy to give [permissions to edit a specific page in django cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/advanced/permissions_reference.html)

However, I didn't find a way to give a permission to edit a page in a certain language.

It's a very common scenario, I have my Spanish, Russian and English editors, and I want that everyone will be able to edit only the pages in their language.

Is there a way of doing it that i'm missing? and if not, what can be done to solve it?

Comment: +1. I thought that at first you could simply create a group per language and assign the different editors to their group but of course the page permissions aren't granular enough. You should ask on the django-cms group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-cms as well as github (if it turns out to be a missing feature) https://github.com/divio/django-cms

Answer (score 1):

At this moment there is an overhaul done of the page permission in Django CMS. One of the things they want to solve is Permission per language.

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4598

If everything goes well, it will be released in DjangoCMS 3.4

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is [no way](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L838) to set permissions on a page+language basis. 
The remaining options are to [submit a feature request](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/new) or fork django-cms and implement on your own.